# Eth goerli syncmode light, after reaching to the updated block it stops updating the new blocks chain

Tags: go-ethereum, goerli, prysm

I am running eth latest version (1.12.0-stable-e501b3b0) and prysm latest version (v4.0.6). I have removed the .ethereum directory and start the eth goerli syncmode light but after reaching to the updated block it stops updating the new blocks chain.

Eth Logs:

conn=127.0.0.1:40404 reqid=2  duration=3.001766904s  err="no suitable peers available"
conn=127.0.0.1:40404 reqid=3  duration="12.811µs"    err="the method engine_newPayloadV2 does not exist/is not available"
Served eth_call conn=127.0.0.1:49256 reqid=3 duration=12.00540214s  err="getDeleteStateObject (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) error: no suitable peers available"

Prysm Logs:

info msg="Processing block batch of size 47 starting from  0xfc25e4f4... 6018592/6054555 - estimated time remaining 29m58s" blocksPerSecond=20.0 peers=56 prefix=initial-sync
warning msg="Skip processing batched blocks" error="beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0xd3ec5a1097bf85700a19b2d2034e9e42f10df839ab9e5afde20aaa83334e0617 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=6018592)" prefix=initial-sync
error msg="Could not compute head from new attestations" error="head at slot 6018175 with weight 0 is not eligible, finalizedEpoch, justified Epoch 188068, 188067 != 188068, 188068" prefix=blockchain

And its working fine when i run eth goerli with sync mode snap.